# change aws launch template name

Tags: amazon-web-services, launch-configuration

I'm new to aws. How can I change AWS launch template name? 
I tried to run the command:

```
aws ec2 modify-launch-template --launch-template-id <ID> --launch-template-name <NEW_LAUNCH_TEMPLATE_NAME>
```

or adding the 'Name' tag, but without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the name of a LaunchConfiguration, there is no ModifyLaunchConfiguration [API call available](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/APIReference/API_Operations.html).

However, you can create a new LaunchConfiguration with your new, desired name, based on the current one. There is the DescribeLaunchConfiguration call, which will give you the current details.

Note that the CLI uses lower-case-with-dashes (`create-launch-configuration`) for the API names, while the documentation uses CamelCase (`CreateLaunchConfiguration`).

Comment: okay thank you! but how can I change later the auto scaling group on my managed node group? beacuse it's created by the node group..